# Prove that f is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

**The problem:**

Prove or refute the following:

> If $f,g,h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f \circ g \circ h$ is surjective then $f$ is surjective.

My solution:
(The definition of surjective: iff $∀y ∈ T ,∃x ∈ S \implies f(x) = y$)

Let $f\colon A \to B$, $g\colon B \to C$ and $h: C \to D$.

Lets say $b ∈ A$, $a ∈  B$. We know by definition that $f(g(h(a)) = b$

Therefore $f(a) = b$, $g(a) = b$, $h(a)=b$, so $f$ is surjective.

I am kind of confused (as you can see from my solution)
Please help, am I at least on the right track or completely wrong.

Comment: You missed the definitions of functions. Following your definition $f(g(x)):A \to B$, but $g:B\to C$, so $f(g())=f(C)$ but we know nothing about $C$ and $f$.

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused. You're given that $f,g,h$ are all functions from $R$ to $R$, so what's that about $A,B,C$ and $D$? You're hypothesis is that $\forall b\in R\exists a\in R(f(g(h(a)))=b)$ and you want to prove that $\forall y\in R\exists x\in R(f(x)=y)$. So take an arbitrary $y$. You need to find a suitable $x$. Use the hypothesis with $b:=y$ and find $x$.

Comment: I think people were too quick to read 'R' as '$\mathbb R$'. Specially since this is not only true in general, but also because the proof looks exactly the same, nothing about the real numbers is used.

Comment: @Git Gud I agree, and I was the culprit who changed $R$ to $\mathbb{R}$ in the text of the question. Should we change it back?

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic Actually it wasn't you. If you go to the [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1460891/revisions)you'll see someone did it before you. In any case the answerers posted their answers before any edit was made, so they also made the same mistake of reading '$\mathbb R$'. Should you change '$\mathbb R$' to $R$? I think that's for the best unless the OP opposes it.

Comment: Why is this tagged (relations)?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777132/proving-a-function-is-surjective-given-the-composition-is-surjective) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229065/if-f-circ-g-is-onto-then-f-is-onto-and-if-f-circ-g-is-one-to-one-then-g).

Answer (score 8):

Let $y\in\mathbb{R}$. As $f\circ g\circ h$ is surjective, there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(f\circ g\circ h)(x) = y$.
So, if we let $x' = (g\circ h)(x)$, we have $f(x') = y$,
which proves that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb{R}=(f\circ g\circ h) (\mathbb{R})\subseteq{f(\mathbb{R}})\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, so $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$.

**even**
$f\colon E \to F$, $g\colon D \to E$ and $h: C \to D$, then since $\mathbb{F}=(f\circ g\circ h) (\mathbb{C})\subseteq{f(E})\subseteq \mathbb{F}$, so $f(\mathbb{E})=F$.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you got to

> Therefore f(a) = b , g(a) = b , h(a) =b , so f is surjective.

by the way you don't need A,B,C and D because you know by definition of f,g,h that they go from R to R..... so A,B,C,D would simply be R

As you said we know per definition $\forall y \in R\; \exists x\in R : f(g(h(x)))=y$ Then simply substitude $g(h(x))$ by $x'$ now you have $\forall y \in R\; \exists x'\in R: g(x')=y$ . But thats excactly the definition of surjective so you'r finished....

PS: be carful with the notation $f\circ g \circ h $ because it's not clearly defined wether it means $f(g(h(x)))$ or $h(g(f(x)))$

Comment: Thank you so much Börge, I finally understood it

Comment: Very important points. Plus the fact that you don't unnecessarily do it for the real numbers (+1).